# Add images from post in wordpress to flexslider

Tags: php, html, wordpress, content-management-system, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying to add images from wordpress to my php page. I have already called the wp-load.php for wordpress:

```
require_once("blog/wp-load.php");
```

However, I do not know how to call a specific post where in I could use the images in that post to go to my flex-slider.

```
<div class="flexslider">
     <ul class="slides">
    <li><img src="<?php
     //????
   ?>" />
```

How do I call a specific post, then from that specific post I could get all the images filepath, then paste it on the src of the image? I wanted it to be inside a post, so if ever I want to change the image, I just edit the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using get_posts()?

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment',
      'posts_per_page' => -1, 
      'post_status' => 'any', 
      'post_parent' => **THE_ID_OF_THE_POST** );
$attachments = get_posts( $args );
//ETC...
```